# Set 410 status in unique scenarios

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, http-status-code-410

I have discovered some of my dev sites have been indexed by Google. Somehow the robots.txt was removed. How can I tweak my .htaccess to give a 410 status if the visitor is the google spider bot OR the visit is a referral from google?

Comment: why not setting up a htpasswd on them?

Comment: How was the *robots.txt was removed*? Isn't this your real problem

Comment: I think it goes without saying the robots.txt is back in place and things are password protected. So, no that is not the real problem. The real problem is having these links removed from the Google index, thus serving up a 410.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=410]
```

Comment: This works great. Amazing. Didn't realize stringing together conditions was that easy!